# How does the SE search return results so quickly?

Tags: discussion, search, architecture, technology

Stack Exchange's built-in search returns results really really quickly. Are the pages spidered and indexed? Is there some schema optimization in use? I'm just curious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're using the new mind-reading features in .NET 4.0, so the server already knows what you're going to search for (and starts looking) before you even hit the submit button.

But seriously.  :)

I believe they're using SQL Server full-text search (is this covered in one of the FAQs?) so yes, everything is "spidered and indexed"...

*edit* here's a [blog post](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2008/11/stackoverflows-sql-2008-fts-issue-solved/) that mentions them in the same sentence...  :)

Answer (score 4):

An enslaved army of highly trained monkeys.

Comment: Don't forget the typewriters

Comment: As opposed to Google which, as everyone knows, uses pigeons, as in the famous Google PigeonRank (TM) system.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that SO doesn't have to search eleventy-billion or so web pages like Google does.  It's more like 350,000 questions.  Many databases are much larger than that.

Answer (score -1):

Mainly because it's not a very good search.  It is easy to return bad search results fast.

Comment: Is this "hide behind wiki friday" or "im going to make a comment an answer wednesday"?

Comment: "It is easy to return bad search results fast." :) Funny but not true.

Comment: hey it's a running gag that SO site search sucks. i'm not the first to point it out.

Comment: used to be true, but not any more (see recent changes http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search). We just hadn't had time to work on it much, and it was low-pri since Google works so well.